# MapIndexed stops at levelspec 1 if only the index is passed?

Tags: expression-manipulation, map

If the function passed to MapIndexed references the first (or data) argument, the following performs as expected:

```
MapIndexed[#2 &, 1 -> {2 -> {3 -> 4}}, Infinity]
```

As well as

```
MapIndexed[(#1; #2) &, 1 -> {2 -> {3 -> 4}}, Infinity]
```

yield:

```
{1} -> {2}
```

Not respecting the Infinity level spec,

whereas:

```
MapIndexed[{#1, #2} &, 1 -> {2 -> {3 -> 4}}, Infinity]
```

gives

```
{1, {1}} -> {{{{2, {2, 1, 
       1}} -> {{{{3, {2, 1, 2, 1, 1}} -> {4, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2}}, {2, 1, 
         2, 1}}}, {2, 1, 2}}, {2, 1}}}, {2}}
```

Comment: You can show it on simple example: `MapIndexed[#2 &, 1 -> {2 -> {3 -> 4}}, Infinity]`. `#2&` is loosing information about `#` so this is what I'd expect, isn't it?

Comment: beat me too it..  suggest you edit the question with a simpler example. The example has some syntax error anyway.

Comment: @Kuba I think it's not so simple. We could imagine a different action, where all parts are simply replaced by their positions, while heads are preserved. I think, they key point is that `MapIndexed` acts depth-first, leaves before branches. No idea why this one was down voted.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It was not me who did that. My previous comment mentioned that "leaves before branches" thing but then I've thought it should not matter. I have to re-think it :)

Comment: @Kuba May be you're right. If we anyway replace the element with position, we probably lose this info either way.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I do think someone with 2k rep should know to provide a minimal example..  You can see the same with lists by the way eg `MapIndexed[#2 &, {a, {b, c}}, Infinity]`

Comment: @george2079, you're right re minimal example and edited accordingly using Kuba's prior example.

Comment: What is your real goal? What ultimate use will you make of the index positions? BTW, you can get the index positions in question by evaluating `Position[1 -> {2 -> {3 -> 4}}, i_Integer]`

Comment: Like so many things, in order to cull this from the docs you need to drill way down to "scope" and "level specifications" and read all the way down to the bottom of that..

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks, Position is preferable for some tasks. The larger goals are (1) parse and process JSON data (2) develop data frame functionality (eg R)

Answer (score 4):

This already seems to be answered in the comments, but since some 40+ minutes have passed I'll post it myself.

Using george's example and [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trace.html) it's pretty clear what happens:

```
MapIndexed[#2 &, {a, {b, c}}, Infinity]
```

Is transformed into:

> ```
> {(#2&)[a,{1}],(#2&)[{(#2&)[b,{2,1}],(#2&)[c,{2,2}]},{2}]}
> ```

From there it evaluates as usual and so you end up with parts like:

> ```
> (#2&)[{{2,1},{2,2}},{2}]
> ```

Where the inner data that you constructed is thrown away, leaving only `{2}`, producing a final expression of:

> ```
> {{1}, {2}}
> ```

Comment: @Kuba I only saw this question a few minutes ago, but since you had the answer long before and didn't post it I assumed you were not going to.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ok thanks. How do you suggest mapping all the index positions in the expression? Seems a hack to pass the #1 parameter and later project it out.

Comment: @alancalvitti It is not clear to me what output you expect.  Would you please post a new question?